# Issue with `echo` in bash when looping over output of python script

Tags: bash, shell-script, python, echo, for

Given the python script

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("first")
    print("second")
    print("third")
```

the bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a choice=$( python3 test.py )
echo "You chose "
for c in "${choice[@]}"; do
    echo "> ${c}"
done
```

should print

```
You chose
> first
> second
> third
```

but instead, it prints

```
You chose
> first
second
third
```

Why is that, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python script prints three lines with text.  To read these into an array in `bash`, use `readarray`:

```
readarray -t chose < <( python3 test.py )
printf '> %s\n' "${chose[@]}"
```

The `readarray -t` command will read lines into the given array from standard input.  Standard input is redirected from your Python script using a process substitution.  The `readarray` utility will by default read individual lines, i.e. strings of text terminated by a newline, and the `-t` option makes the utility remove the terminating newline from the data that is read.

The `printf` call prints each array element with a leading `>` and space.
Giving multiple arguments to `printf`, which you do by giving it the expansion of an array like this, it will reuse its formatting string for outputting each individual argument.  This means there is no need for a loop.

---

The issue with your script is that you are reading the output from your Python script into a single string.  The command substitution `$( python3 test.py )` would be expanded to a string that you then would have to manually parse and split on newlines into the correct array elements.

You could do [as Dabombber suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/532415/116858) and let the shell do this splitting for you with `choice=( $( python test.py ) )` (the `declare -a` is not needed), but note that this would split the string on *any* whitespace (spaces, tabs and newlines (the contents of `$IFS`) by default), which may not be what you want if you want your individual array elements to include spaces.

An option then would possibly be to set `IFS` to a newline to get the shell to split the data on newlines *only*, or to read the output for the Python code with `read`, and these may be good solutions, but you have the `readarray` built-in utility in `bash` which makes this easier.

---

It looks (judging from the variable name and other text in your code) that you may want to implement some sort of interactive menu.

This could also be done with `select` in `bash`:

```bash
readarray -t options < <( python3 test.py )

echo 'Please select your option' >&2
PS3='Your selection: '
select ch in "${options[@]}"; do
    [ -n "$ch" ] && break
    echo 'Invalid, try again' >&2
done

printf 'You chose option %d ("%s")\n' "$REPLY" "$ch"
```

This would use the output of your Python script as options in a `select` loop.  The loop would continue until a valid option has been selected by the user.  At the end, the picked option (and its number) is printed.

The `PS3` prompt is the prompt used by `select` in `bash`.  The default value is `#?` followed by a space.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `declare -a choice=$( python3 test.py )` making a 1 length array where

```
choice[0]='first
second
third'
```

Try `declare -a choice=( $( python3 test.py ) )`